# Subprocess.Popen not returning control when invoked from ansible yml file

Tags: java, python, powershell, ansible, subprocess

I have written ansible yml files to call from jenkins for deployment of my java project on **Windows** server.
In my deploy.yml file I am calling python script as below:

```
    -name: start service
     Win_command:: "powershell.exe python startService.py {{param1}}"
     args:
       chdir: "{{temp}}"
```

In my startService.py, code to run java service is as below:

```
    with open("stdout.log","wb") as out , open("stderr.err","wb") as err:

      proc = subprpcess.Popen("javaw -jar sample1.jar",shell=False,stdout=out,stderr=err)
      pid=proc.pid
```

When I run startService.py from command line using powershell it works fine by starting the service and exits , means python script is completed.
but when I invoke this via Jenkins using ansible deploy.yml it starts the service but that task runs forever till service is up. When we kill it, then task shows completed and goes to next task.

as I am deploying on **Windows**, not able to utilize any linux supported params.
please help me what can I do here.
I want to use this python way only as its easy to capture pid and few other things.

Comment: You should not use `shell=False` here. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) _If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments._

Comment: To clarify, is your goal to start `sample1.jar` but not wait for its completion?

Comment: Thanks tdelaney, I am passing many arguments as variable but skipped them here just to keep it simple. Even when its successfully started , ansible is waiting forever as may be writing to log file is not finished. I just want to start the jar and come out